# Grails + Struts Tiles

Tags: java, jsp, grails, tiles

Have someone there any experience with integrating [Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) into [Grails](http://grails.org/) (instead of SiteMesh)?

I found a few articles like this: http://devdevdev.wordpress.com/2009/01/ and as i understand at least one year ago there was no way to use Tiles inside Grails. Maybe something changed last time? Has anyone tried to do it?

ps. or maybe there are exists an another plugin for grails, that allows me to use [Composite View design pattern](http://tiles.apache.org/tutorial/pattern.html)?

Comment: As of 2013, are there any updates to this question?

Comment: No updates, don't see any way to use Tiles with Grails

Comment: Btw, in 2013, we prefer to use rich js ui, on client side. Angular/Backbone/etc. So it's not so important anymore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never tried but django templates are awsome see DjangoTemplates Plugin http://www.grails.org/DjangoTemplates+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of default plugins in new grails project. It seems that SiteMash is not a part of grails as a plugin. So it will be hard to replace with Tiles.

Default plugin list:

- i18n - 1.3.3
- filters - 1.3.3
- logging - 1.3.3
- core - 1.3.3
- tomcat - 1.3.3
- dataSource - 1.3.3
- groovyPages - 1.3.3
- urlMappings - 1.3.3
- controllers - 1.3.3
- servlets - 1.3.3
- codecs - 1.3.3
- scaffolding - 1.3.3
- domainClass - 1.3.3
- mimeTypes - 1.3.3
- hibernate - 1.3.3
- converters - 1.3.3
- services - 1.3.3
- validation - 1.3.3

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to deviate from standard templating in Grails. We tried to deviate to xhtml templating in grails 1.1.1 but in initial 1 hour I realized it will be tough. I am not sure if there is some easy options/plugin in grails 1.3.3